# xcode 9.2 iOS swift timer

Tags: swift, xcode, nstimer

I used Xcode and swift a few years ago and have now returned and I'm trying to make a timer that execute a procedure every second. But with this new swift and Xcode 9.2, NSTimer and Timer.scheduledTimer no longer exist ans I can't find any documentation on how you make a timer in this new version of Xcode. Can any one help and tell me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us some code. Maybe we could point out what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 4, you should use 'Timer':

```
var timer: Timer!
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

In your case, you should set 'repeats' to true. Make sure you invalidate your timer when you're done with it:

```
timer.invalidate()
```

Put "@obj" in front of your function. And you're ready to go.

```
@obj fun runTimedCode() {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Timer.scheduleTimer still exist.
Try to write.

Comment: Sorry, I have restarted Xcode and it is working now.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add a timer to a run loop:

```
let aTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
    //do things. Don't forget about retain cycles.
})
RunLoop.current.add(aTimer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
```

**Edit:**

My bad, didn't notice the question was about scheduled timer. Thanks goes to David Rönnqvist for noticing and correcting me.

Comment: A [scheduled timer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer) is already scheduled on the current run loop in the default mode.